# PHP - Can I put the whole block of function that returns boolean inside the expression in if condition in PHP? Ex: if( function() { return true; })

Tags: php, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I created a conditional statement in **PHP** lately. I've been bothered if I can put the whole block of a **function** inside the parenthesis or the expression in **IF** condition. For example:

```
if( ! function($some_vars) {
     //Execute logic of the function here
     return false;
}) {
     // Execute if the function above returns false;
}
```

PS: The code above does not return any error but does not execute the logic inside the function either. My question is: **Are the code above possible and if this is possible, is it safe/recommended**?

Thanks!

Comment: you just declare anonymous function but don't call it, try to add parentheses after declaration. but i don't know if it would work ))

Comment: It is not recommended because it is __unreadable__.

Comment: I don't know what you need a function for, you should be able to put any necessary expressions inside the `if` condition without a function wrapper. If the function body is so long and contains statements that you can't express in an expression, **then it shouldn't be in an `if` condition.**

Comment: Why don't you just do `function myFunction() { ... return false }` and then `if (! myFunction() ) { ... }` ?

Comment: Okay I created functions like you do @MickaelLeger for years, but this morning I came up with this code not thinking if it is readable. My bad!

Comment: @JhunieRaySuarez the question is not stupid, but I'm ok with most of anwser : it's not readable and the logic is strange ! Still interesting to know why :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func.php) to execute such function right now:

```
if(!call_user_func(function($some_vars) {
     //Execute logic of the function here
     var_dump($some_vars);
     return false;
},"a variable called some_vars")) {
     var_dump("yes");
}
```

But as it's not recommended because of readability. So the following code is more readable:

```
function checkSomeVar($some_vars) {
     //Execute logic of the function here
     var_dump($some_vars);
     return false;
}

if(!checkSomeVar("a variable called some_vars")) {
   var_dump("yes");
}
```

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should… 

Comment: Thanks @Blauharley! I've been doing that for years. I was just curious  and came up with that code this morning without thinking if it is readable.

Comment: @JhunieRaySuarez: You are welcome. I know exactly what you mean, you sometimes want to test what is possible to write or what are the limits of a language rather than using this code in production ;)